# Using an abstract Java class in Scala

Tags: scala

A Java class is defined as

```
public abstract class A<T> extends B<T>{

  public A(final A1 a1, final A2 a2, final A3 a3) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

It is used in a Java code base as

```
new A<Boo>(a1, a2, a3) {...}
```

If I convert the above Java code to Scala as the following

```
new A[Boo](a1, a2, a3) {...}
```

My IDE tells me "Cannot resolve constructor". A red line crosses the portion A[Boo]. I believe that it isn't for Boo, but A since I get the same error with a Java class named Boo. When I compile the code, I get an error message

```
overloaded method constructor A with alternatives
```

What is a good approach to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code, and was able to compile your example on JDK 8. The problem must be hiding somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, it is compiled with Java 8. That is what the project SDK setup.